# Is there way to automate emulator android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I have to do test plan for an android application. There are about 120 screens in the application and I have to check the app for several emulators. Problem is it takes too much time. I know how to take screen shots with eclipse IDE. I want to automate the process. I cant find that eclipse provide such kind of facility.I am really tired of taking screen shots one by one.

Comment: 120 screen !!! How did you do that ??

Comment: yes it is more than 120 screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`Robotium`** to automate going through the screens and take the screenshot with that.

Look [there](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers):

Can I take screenshots from inside of Robotium?

Yes you can. Use `takeScreenshot()` to save a screenshot in "`/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/`". Observe that this functionality requires write permission (`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) in the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the application under test.

Comment: I have large scrollable text view. In that case, is there way to capture whole textview ? If one text view can not be taken to one screenshot, can we handle this?

Comment: It won't be able to capture the whole thing, but Robotium should let you scroll down (of course, there will be some programming involved)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [ManyMo](http://www.manymo.com/). Its very simple and you can get all kinds of emulators of different devices.

Comment: I think this is online tool. I can not upload my apk to others site "(